# Send Change Event Programmatically

Tags: javascript

I have a field, and I want to add text with some javascript, which works, then I save and it disappear because change event is missing.

I tried this, usually it works but not this time.

```js
var o = document.getElementById('contactPerson'); if (document.createEvent) 
    {
            var evt = document.createEvent('Events'); 
            evt.initEvent('change', true, true); 
            o.dispatchEvent(evt); 
      }
```

```html
    <div class="input-default contactPerson">
    <div><span data-meta="Field" class="next-input next-large">
<input id="contactPerson" placeholder="Nom et prénom" name="contactPerson" height="100%" autocomplete="off" value="Mme welaval featrice 13D"></span><p class="error-msg"></p></div><p class="tips"> Exemple : Martin Claire </p></div>
```

console tell s me this event is executed when I write manualy :

```
> e: "change"     n: Event
    .   bubbles: true     cancelBubble: false     cancelable: false     composed: false     currentTarget: document     defaultPrevented: false     eventPhase: 3     isTrusted: true     path: Array(17)
    .   0: input#contactPerson
```

Comment: Q: What exactly is your question?  Q: Why don't you simply override the input tag's [onchange](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp) event hander?  Q: Would you consider using [jQuery](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_change.asp)?

Comment: I want to add text and keep it after saving, otherwise it disappears or put back previous text.   let s try jquery  ))

Comment: try `new CustomEvent`. see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent

Comment: So you are saving the form, and the content of the input disappears? If so that isn't an event problem,

Comment: it erase the new input and put back the precedent, like I didn't do anything

Comment: So it does erase the content on form submission?

Comment: it erase what I added with a script, it put back what was before. I checked on others fields and it s same. Every field have change event so if I don fire it, the fields is going back as precedent on save. I need to find a way to fire the change event, I spend a day on that ))

Comment: if I stroke my keyboard and save then it s saved what I wrote, now if I add same text with a script and save then it  erase what I added and put back what was before.